# How to interpret confci function from model prediction? Why may not this match up to the bootstrap CI plot on ggplot2?

Tags: r, lme4, confidence-interval

I am trying to reconcile the confidence intervals seen on the ggplot (by using bootstrapped CI) and that when I compute CI from the lmer model. I am unsure how to calculate the CI. How would I then plot the original points, with new mean and predicted CI?

```
set.seed(111)
oviposition.index <- rnorm(20, 2, 1.3)
species <- rep(c("A","B"), each = 10)
month <- rep(c("Jan", "Feb"), times = 10)
plot <- rep(c("1", "2"), times = 10)
df <- data.frame(oviposition.index, species, month, plot)

mod <- lmer(oviposition.index ~ species + (1|month/plot), df)
summary(mod)
confint(mod)
```

Model summary and confidence intervals

```
Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error      df t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept)   1.1303     0.3684  3.5822   3.068   0.0432 *
speciesB      0.8198     0.5131 17.0000   1.598   0.1285 



                2.5 %   97.5 %
.sig01       0.0000000 1.130819
.sig02       0.0000000 1.130819
.sigma       0.8232305 1.540289
(Intercept)  0.3600376 1.900525
speciesB    -0.1836920 1.823253
```

The way I see it:
Species A:

Lower CI = 1.1303 - 0.3600376 = 0.7702624 (DOES NOT match graph)

Upper CI = 1.1303 + 1.900525 = 3.030825 (DOES NOT match graph)

Species B:

Lower CI = 0.8198 - (-0.1836920 )= 1.003492 (roughly matches graph)

Upper CI = 0.8198 + (1.823253) = 2.643053 (roughly matches graph)

Plot shows

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = species, y = oviposition.index, color = species)) + geom_point() +
   geom_hline(yintercept = 1) + 
   stat_summary(fun.data=mean_cl_boot, geom="errorbar", width=0.2, colour="black") + 
   stat_summary(fun = mean, color = "black", geom ="point", size = 3,show.legend = FALSE)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A few more points to add to @Nate's answer.

The idea that the bootstrap function from `Hmisc` (which is what `mean_cl_boot` uses) is wrong because it doesn't take the grouping structure into account is basically correct.

I modified your fitting function slightly to make it more convenient to look at the confidence intervals for species A (suppressing the intercept by including `-1` in the formula. I also tried it with and without `lmerTest`, for the purpose of making some comparisons discussed in more detail below.

```r
library(lme4)
mod0 <- lmer(oviposition.index ~ species-1 + (1|month/plot), df)
library(lmerTest)
mod1 <- as(mod0, "lmerModLmerTest")

library(broom.mixed)

f <- function(m, mod = mod0, ...) {
  tt <- tidy(mod, conf.int = TRUE, effects = "fixed", conf.method = m, ...)
  as.data.frame(tt)[1, c("estimate", "conf.low", "conf.high")]
}
ctab <- rbind(
    hmboot = Hmisc::smean.cl.boot(oviposition.index[1:10]),
    hmwald = Hmisc::smean.cl.normal(oviposition.index[1:10]),
    wald = f("Wald"),
    wald_t_satt = f("Wald", mod1),
    wald_t_kr = f("Wald", mod1, ddf.method = "Kenward-Roger"),
    profile = f("profile"),
    pboot = f("boot")
)
print(ctab,digits =3)
```

- a *Wald test* is based on the estimated curvature of the likelihood surface at the ML estimate. It's usually fastest but least accurate; it always gives *symmetric* CIs. It can be based on the assumption of a Normal sampling distribution of the estimate or based on a t-distribution; if the latter, then you need to specify some method of approximating the 'degrees of freedom' parameter of the t distribution.
- *profile likelihood* is based on measuring the whole likelihood surface. It's more reliable (and slower) than Wald, but doesn't take small sample sizes into account
- *parametric bootstrap* is the most reliable, but slowest method. It is based on simulating new data sets from the model.

Conclusions here are that the methods all give *approximately* the same estimates for the CI. The naive bootstrap (as you've used above) gives the (slightly) narrowest CIs, and the Wald estimate with Kenward-Roger degrees of freedom gives the widest (probably overconservative, as the parametric bootstrap (`pboot`) probably gives the best answer). (The Satterthwaite ddf approximation completely breaks down in this example.)

```
            estimate conf.low conf.high  
hmboot          1.13   0.4397      1.68 ## naive bootstrap
hmwald          1.13   0.4005      1.86 ## naive Wald (t-distrib)
wald_lmer       1.13   0.4082      1.85 ## mixed-model Wald (Z-distrib)
wald_t_satt     1.13      NaN       NaN ## mixed-model Wald (Satterthwaite)
wald_t_kr       1.13   0.0586      2.20 ## mixed-model Wald (Kenward-Roger)
profile         1.13   0.3600      1.90 ## likelihood profile CI
pboot           1.13   0.4111      1.82 ## parametric bootstrap CI
```

[image: estimates and various confidence intervals]

If we get a little fancier (code below) we can get CIs for both groups:

[image: CIs for both species]

```r
library(Hmisc)
f <- function(m, mod = mod0, w = 1:2, ...) {
  tt <- tidy(mod, conf.int = TRUE, effects = "fixed", conf.method = m, ...)
  tt[1:2, c("term","estimate", "conf.low", "conf.high")]
}

h <- function(sfun) {
  tab <- do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df, species),
                               function(d) sfun(d$oviposition.index)))
  tab <- data.frame(term = paste0("species", c("A","B")),
                    setNames(as.data.frame(tab), c("estimate", "conf.low", "conf.high")))
  return(tab)
}
h(smean.cl.normal)

tab2 <- dplyr::bind_rows(list(
    hmisc_boot = h(smean.cl.boot),
    hmisc_normal = h(smean.cl.normal),
    wald_lmer = f("Wald"),
    wald_t_satt = f("Wald", mod1),
    wald_t_kr = f("Wald", mod1, ddf.method = "Kenward-Roger"),
    profile = f("profile"),
    boot = f("boot")),
    .id = "method")

tab2$method <- factor(tab2$method, levels = unique(tab2$method))
ggplot(tab2, aes(x=term, y = estimate, colour = method)) +
  geom_pointrange(aes(ymin=conf.low, ymax = conf.high), position = position_dodge(width=0.25)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 1, lty = 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

The confidence intervals won't be the same because your mixed effects model has grouping variables that `ggplot`'s (really `Hmisc`'s) boot CI function doesn't have. Ultimately this leeds to the mixed effect model estimating more error in this scenario, which we see in the CIs.

That said the CIs from `lmer` are close to what you have plotted already. `groupA` (Intercept) is 1.1303 mu and 0.3684 se, and `groupB` is ~1.94 mu (1.13 + 0.81) and more variance with 0.5131 se.  I don't think your interpretation of group differences will change with either one of the CI calculations.